# How can I use Youtube API's access token to get the list of user's uploded video

Tags: php, api, video, youtube

I have already get the access token of user via Oauth2, so after authenticate user to my Project and ask them to manage their Youtube data i am storing access token to the DB

Now i want to get the detail or list of the video that uploaded by that authenticated user, so How can I use user's access token to get their Youtube video data?

Below is my code

I generate the Authentication Url like

```
$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";  
$params = array(
"response_type" => "code",
"client_id" => "XXXXXXX",
"redirect_uri" => "http://youtube-get.dev/oauth2callback.php",
"scope" => "https://gdata.youtube.com",
"access_type" => "offline"
);
$request_to = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
header("Location: " . $request_to);
```

And by calling curl in oauth2callback.php I get the Access Token

```
$client_id="XXXXXXX";
$client_secret="XXXXXX";
$redirect_uri="http://youtube-get.dev/oauth2callback.php";

$oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$clienttoken_post = array(
"code" => $code,
"client_id" => $client_id,
"client_secret" => $client_secret,
"redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
"grant_type" => "authorization_code"
);

$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$authObj = json_decode($json_response);

if (isset($authObj->refresh_token)){
    //refresh token only granted on first authorization for offline access
    //save to db for future use (db saving not included in example)
    global $refreshToken;
    $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
}

$accessToken = $authObj->access_token;
```

After getting this Access token how can i use it to get authenticated user's video list?

All the help will be appreciated, already wasted much time for it.

Comment: Please, show us some of your current work and point where is the problem inside it, as well as the expected behavior and a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok i have included my code, whatever i have done till now

Answer (score -1):

after authentication use below url to get authenticate users video

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&maxResults=25&q={your searchparameter}&type=video&key={your App Key}
```